# How to connect/disconnect OpenVPN from CLI in Ubuntu 18

Tags: openvpn

Some guides suggest connecting from client with this command:
`sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn`

But they only tell you how to disconnect with GUIs and I'm in the CLI.

1) Is this the best CLI way to connect from client machine?
2) What's the best way to close the connection (and possibly bring the interface down)?  `sudo kill <pid>` seems wrong but perhaps that's what you're supposed to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VPN client is just an executable, like any other, so you stop it like any other. I use this for work every day and I open my connection with `sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn` and then close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You don't need anything else.

Now, actually, `sudo kill PID` will do exactly the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so you can use that too if you like, but there's no reason to. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal window is faster and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Press control + C in the terminal window in which you run the openvpn.

Answer (score 1):

start client `sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn --management 127.0.0.1 999`
kill client `echo "signal SIGTERM"|nc 127.0.0.1 999`

Comment: Honestly, this is the best solution!